# Profiling Service Fabric Application

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I have built a service fabric application which contains stateless and stateful services.
When the user hits stateless endpoint(API), the API internally calls stateful service through proxy call and send the response.

Here, I want to check the execution time of each component so started checking profiling tools but I didn't find any good tool.

If anyone is using any tool to check CPU time and execution time of API/ service methods, Please let us know.

Comment: Hi,  Is Peter's answer helpful to your issue

Answer (score 0):

You could enable the [Application Insights integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-analysis-appinsights). A full tutorial on how to setup the integration in code can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-monitoring-aspnet).

Application insights (an Azure SaaS offering) will collect performance related metrics and show what calls where made and how long they took.

If you want to profile your service manually you can use interception techniques to create your own metrics. I created a small library that makes it easier to intercept method calls, see [this](https://github.com/Expecho/ServiceFabric-Remoting-CustomHeaders) repo.